# sub figure numbering Issue

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, subfloats

I am facing an issue related to a subfigure caption. That is, I have two figures: *figure 5* and then after that *figure 3*. I also have *figure 8* and I want this figure as labelled as *figure 5a*. Simply, one figure number is 5, and another figure number is 8, and I need to make *figure 8* appear as *figure 5a*. Kindly help me resolve it.

Comment: without to see your (minimal) code is difficult (impossible) to say, why your figures is not numbered as you wish. Apparently you have some mismatch in code ...

Comment: @Zarko I'm not sure there is some mismatch. I have the impression the edits might have changed the original meaning of the question. I can read the original question as: I have Fig. 5, then 3 figures later Fig. 8, and I want this one to be called 5a. To which I would reply: why on Earth would you want that `:-)`?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a bruteforce solution, and I'm not sure this is what you meant, but you can locally change the numbering of a figure by `\renewcommand\thefigure{}`

MWE (which you failed to supply and I had to do from scratch)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height = 4cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{First figure}
    \end{figure}

    \lipsum[2]

    \begin{figure}[b]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height = 4cm]{example-image-b}
        \renewcommand\thefigure{1a}
        \caption{First figure}
    \end{figure}

    \lipsum[3]

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height = 4cm]{example-image-c}
        \caption{First figure}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm still convince that OP has some mess in her/his document and than we can't help her/him before she/he will provide minimal but complete document which we can copy  and test. If this will not happen soon, I will suggest to close question as "unclear what you're asking".  Your nice answer is based on pure guessing and probably not resolve OP problem.

Comment: true, but it might show up on a search and prevent some other question :)